# C# Repeater gives exception on NEXT Button Click : 'ddlPageNo' has a SelectedIndex which is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I am using repeater to load data, it shows following exception on Next button click in following scenario

I have to dropdown 
1. it shows number of pages (ddlPageNo)
2. it shows how many rows I want to show(ddlPageSize)

so when I have 9 values and if I keep value of 2nd dropdown(ddlPageSize) 10 
and click the next button then it gives  exception

> 'ddlPageNo' has a SelectedIndex which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

there is my code :

```
 void fillRepeater(PageNavigation pageNavigate, string strMode)
   {
        IUser objUser = (clsUser)FactoryUser.getUser();
        DataTable dtUsers = null;
        DataView dvUsers = new DataView();
        PagedDataSource pdsUsers = new PagedDataSource();
        try
        {

            dvUsers = getUsers(strMode);
            pdsUsers.DataSource = dvUsers;
            pdsUsers.AllowPaging = true;
            dvUsers.Sort = "UserName asc";
            pdsUsers.PageSize = Int16.Parse(ddlPageSize.SelectedValue);
            int iPageCount = pdsUsers.PageCount;

            if (ddlPageNo.Items.Count != iPageCount)
            {
                ddlPageNo.Items.Clear();
                for (int kk = 1; kk <= iPageCount; kk++)
                {
                    ListItem lstPage = new ListItem(kk.ToString(), kk.ToString());
                    ddlPageNo.Items.Add(lstPage);
                }
                ddlPageNo.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }


            switch (pageNavigate)
            {
                case PageNavigation.Next:
                    UserViewCurrentPage++;
                    ddlPageNo.SelectedIndex = UserViewCurrentPage;
                    break;
                case PageNavigation.Previous:
                    UserViewCurrentPage--;
                    ddlPageNo.SelectedIndex = UserViewCurrentPage;
                    break;
                case PageNavigation.Last:

                    UserViewCurrentPage = pdsUsers.PageCount - 1;
                    ddlPageNo.SelectedIndex = UserViewCurrentPage;
                    break;
                case PageNavigation.Sorting:
                    break;
                case PageNavigation.GotoPage:
                    UserViewCurrentPage = int.Parse(ddlUserPageNo.SelectedValue) - 1;
                    break;
                case PageNavigation.Current:
                    break;
                case PageNavigation.Size:
                    UserViewCurrentPage = 0;
                    ddlPageNo.Items.Clear();
                    if (ddlPageNo.Items.Count == 0)
                    {
                        for (int kk = 1; kk <= iPageCount; kk++)
                        {
                            ListItem lstPage = new ListItem(kk.ToString(), kk.ToString());
                            ddlPageNo.Items.Add(lstPage);
                        }
                        ddlPageNo.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                default: UserViewCurrentPage = 0; ddlPageNo.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    break;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Suppose page size is 5 and number of pages are 2 , if there are 9 values in table so when we click on next button for 1st time 4 values remain on page. so ideally next button must be disabled (which I have achieved with CSS but still that button is clickable ) but it allows to click and on click above exception throws

Comment: Is ViewState enabled on the ddl controls? Have you debugged and checked that ddlPageNo.Items has what you expected on PostBack?

Comment: yes **UserViewCurrentPage** is viewState so it increase after every click on next  button and i am getting right values in ddlPageNo

Comment: Suppose page size is 5 and number of pages are 2 , if there are 9 values  in table so when we click on next button for 1st time 4 values remain on page. so ideally next button must be disabled (which i have achived with CSS but still that button is clickable ) but it allows to click and on click above exception throws